# Views, how to show x-items from each tag?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I wan't to create an view that show MAX:10 items of tags (football,basketball,tenis etc...)

I want the view to show 3 items for each tag

- [football_article_1]
- [football_article_2]
- [football_article_3]
- [basketball_article_1]
- [basketball_article_2]
- .....

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a pre-assigned number of tags, or will people keep adding different ones? In other words, is there a set number of sports from the beginning, or will people keep adding other sports in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution involves creating two views, one of taxonomy terms, and another one of articles, and using [Views Field Fiew](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to embed the article view as a field in the taxonomy terms view.

1. Create a taxonomy term view that shows fields. Add the title (optional) and Term ID fields. We'll come back to this one in a moment.
2. Create a view of content - of your sport articles that contain the tags. You can use an unformatted list of teasers, or if you want to include only some fields, an unformatted list of fields. My example uses teasers. IMPORTANT: Select a limited number of items to display. In my example I'm limiting it to 3. I won't use a pager in this example.
3. In the **Advanced** fieldset of the second view, add **Contextual Filters**. Select **Content: has taxonomy term ID**. Then in **When the filter is not in the URL** : Display content of "no results found".
4. Go back to your taxonomy term view. Add field **Global: View**. Select the View and Display of the view of content created in step 2. IMPORTANT: in the **Contextual filters** textfield, add the token for the Taxonomy term ID field (usually `[%tid]`)

That's it. Visit your taxonomy term view and you'll see a list of 3 articles per term.

This is what the Views UI for the two views look like:

**View of terms**

[image]

**View of content**

[image]

Comment: Ty for answering but i couldn't do it. As an non-cms fan, i tired and i do it hard way. I hacked drupal feeds module. I added an integer field `import_counter`. Foreach FeedItem i insert/RUN, i increase this counter by 1. So, when i import 20 feeditems. each feed item will have the position. Then in views i use filter `import_counter < 3`.

Comment: Well, my answer was very clear and it works, as I have used this many times. It took a long time to write. An up-vote would be nice. Hopefully someone else will find the answer useful.